# How can I get my salary after leaving and boss delaying and being unable to guarantee payment?

Tags: united-kingdom, salaried-pay

I left my job last Friday (25th). The day I was supposed to get paid. My boss sat me down and said he'd be able to get it to me by the 31st (he's been late previously and has paid, so I took his word on it). Now today I've found out he can't guarantee payment to me (a salary), which will mess up my rent and bills. I've already worked the month (my notice). What can I do to get what's rightfully mine?

**Notes**:

- This isn't just me, he hasn't paid the whole office (around 9 employees).
- It's in my contract that he will pay on the last Friday of every month.

Comment: Did the company make any profit last month?

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I don't know, I don't get involved with any of that stuff. I was just a programmer, right now it'd only be an assumption at this point.

Comment: In the UK, isn't there a labor board or worker's rights piece of the governement? If you can sic the authorities on him...do it.

Comment: Sod the job. If you do not have a job to go to then go to the job centre and start claiming benefits. At least you get some money to cover bills, help with rent and council tax. Even if it is for a few weeks

Comment: @joes read my first condition in my first comment.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I very much agree with Joe, going back to work there makes absolutely no sense. The OP left this job for a reason, and surely that situation has not improved now that none of the employees are being paid.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf if an employer doesn't pay you they have frustrated the contract and you are no longer employed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

- The company is in severe financial difficulties and truly doesn't have enough money to cover its liabilities - i.e. it's bankrupt. In that case, you're a creditor and will have to wait for the legal process like anyone else the company owes money to. But don't expect to get anything really.
- Your boss is not paying you because he thinks he can get away with it. If so, start with a strongly worded letter to the company's registered address demanding payment immediately or you will take legal action.

Comment: +1 for the written letter. However, I would suggest OP to go back to their job until they find a new job. their boss did not fire them, and as this answer states: The company might be in a financial troubles for real at the moment, hence why there is a chance to get paid later. Better than just going home.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I left my job for a new job, i'll be starting in two weeks. That money was supposed to cover bills and relocation fees.

Comment: Send the letter using recorded delivery

Comment: @KyleKhalaf  I am sorry, but your comments make no logic sense to most.  The OP has a new job, but even if they did not, how on Earth would it make sense to go back to a job they quit, which is not paying them, may never pay them, and work for free rather than using that time to find a new position?  Hurt themselves and their own efforts to help someone who is in breach of contract?  Bad approach.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - Would a grievance letter count? or would I need to still be employed by the company for that?

Comment: It's not quite true that you should expect to get nothing if your employer is insolvent - in the UK it's possible to claim a limited amount 'from the National Insurance fund' (ie, from government). Some of your claim will be preferred to other creditors, too (though you're still not likely to get much of that).

It's certainly true that it will take a long time, though (and your employer must be in liquidation first). It will not help with your rent and bills, unless we're talking about your rent and bills a year from now.